# Create new file and folder in one step using Windows Command Line redirecting

Tags: windows, command-line

On a Windows Command Line, this would produce a new file called `test.txt`

```
> echo "hello world" > test.txt
```

I would like to create a new file AND a new folder in one step. Something like

```
> echo "hello world" > newFolder\test.txt
```

But it only produces the error: `The system cannot find the path specified.`

Is there any chance to avoid using an extra `mkdir newFolder`?

Answer (score 2):

A quick search and I was unable to find any "trick" but, you can achieve what you want by combining commands on one like like so;

```
mkdir nested && echo "test" > ./nested/test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
mkdir folder_name_here && cd folder_name_here/ && echo "hello world" > test.txt
```

And don't forget to run it IN the directory you want it to save in